# Predefined user groups

Tags: users, user-management

There are a lot of predefined groups on Ubuntu (and many other distros), but I can't seem to find any information about what each is for.  Some seem obvious or are well-known: `cdrom` is for access to optical media devices, and `sudo` is for access to the sudo command.  However, many are ambiguous or not particularly obvious, like `adm`, `sys`, and `tty`--each of those could have many purposes.  Is there complete documentation on this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz`

Comment: Geez, I couldn't find a reference to that file anywhere.  Thanks!